# Como pego o tamanho da tag?

Tags: javascript

To fazendo validação do campo data, o fato é que eu não to conseguindo pegar o tamanho do campo, vejam:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return valida()">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data"/>
    <input type="submit" name="cadastrar"/>
</form>
```

............

```
function valida()
{
    var data = document.querySelector("#data");
    if((data.value == "")||(data.length != 10))
    {
        alert("Informe uma data válida");
        data.focus();
        return false;       
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Mesmo informando uma data correta, tipo "12/12/2012", a função retorna false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou o `.value` antes do `.length` na segunda condição:

```
data.value.length != 10
```

Mas tem parênteses demais na condição. Poderia ser assim:

```
if(!data.value || data.value.length != 10)
```

O `!data.value` já verifica se o campo é vazio.

**Porém** o `!data.value` ainda é redundante, já que o `data.value.length != 10` só irá validar se houver exatos 10 caracteres. Poderia simplesmente ser assim:

```
if(data.value.length != 10)
```

> Só uma observação: para fins de validação de data, checar apenas o
>   número de caracteres não quer dizer que é uma data válida.

Outra coisa, o `return true` não precisa de `else`. Se entrar no `if` retornando `false`, irá sair da função, logo, o `else` é desnecessário:

```
function valida()
{
    var data = document.querySelector("#data");
    if(data.value.length != 10)
    {
        alert("Informe uma data válida");
        data.focus();
        return false;       
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, o return true precisa de else porque faz parte de outro script, aqui eu só peguei um pedaço, e quanto a validação eu sei que ela não é o suficiente ainda.

Comment: Blz. Foram umas dicas gerais mesmo. Mas a questão mesmo é a falta do `.value` antes do `.length`.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não sabia, vou marcar todas.